# How to run testng.xml using command prompt

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I was trying to run testng.xml from command prompt but not able to figure out the following error:

Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

or either

Error: Could not find or load main class java.

While using two different method.

**Please provide a prominent method to do the same.**

Comment: pls describe what you did exactly, what is your whole command line, where did you put the jar file containing your tests, where is the testng jar file etc. which part of the official documentation did you do but ran into problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, but i have solve this problem using Apache ant.

By using following - build.xml

```
<project name="name" basedir=".">
    <!-- ========== Initialize Properties =================================== -->
    <!-- set global properties for build -->
    <property name="basedir" value="." />
    <property name="lib" value="${basedir}/lib" />
    <property name="src" value="${basedir}/src" />
    <property name="bin" value="${basedir}/bin" />
    <property name="report-dir" value="${basedir}/Test-Report" />
    <property name="testng-report-dir" value="${report-dir}/TestNGreport" />

    <!-- ====== Set the classpath ====  -->
    <path id="classpath">
        <pathelement location="${bin}" />
        <fileset dir="${lib}">
            <include name="*.jar" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Delete directories  -->
<target name="delete-dir">
        <delete dir="${bin}" />
        <delete dir="${report-dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Creating directories -->
 <target name="create" depends="delete-dir">
        <mkdir dir="${bin}" />
        <mkdir dir="${report-dir}" />
    </target>

    <!-- Compile the java code from ${src} into ${bin} -->
    <target name="compile" depends="create">
        <javac srcdir="${src}" classpathref="classpath" includeAntRuntime="No" destdir="${bin}" />
        <echo> /* Compiled Directory Classes */ </echo>
    </target>

    <!-- Runs the file and generates Reportng report for TestNG-->
    <taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" classpathref="classpath" />

    <target name="testng-execution" depends="compile">
        <mkdir dir="${testng-report-dir}" />
        <testng outputdir="${testng-report-dir}" classpathref="classpath" useDefaultListeners="true">
            <xmlfileset dir="${basedir}" includes="testng.xml" />
        </testng>
    </target>
</project>
```

**And then by typing: *ant testng-execution* on command prompt**

Answer (score 0):

Paths are separated using `:` under Unix-like systems and not `;` as in Windows:

```
java -cp ./src/lib/*:./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

If you are using bash under Windows, you should use `;` and any other place use `:`.

The `;` character means end of statement to a Unix shell, so what you are probably attempting to execute is:

```
java -cp ./src/lib/*
./bin org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

Comment: it giving me following error: Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException:
No sourcedir was specified
        at org.testng.TestNG.checkConditions(TestNG.java:1170)
        at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1010)
        at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:997)

Comment: I have try this command: java -cp ".;C:\TestNG\testng-6.8.jar" org.testng.TestNG testng.xml  but it giving me:                                                               [TestNG] [Error] Cannot find class in classpath: test_test.Run

Comment: create a bash-file in the project where you src and bin folder is present. As you are using ; so I am supposing you have windows. you do not need testng.jar to pass in the bash file. make sure your testng.xml file have the same name without case sensitive and lastly check your testng.xml file class location of your java file. It should be perfect

Answer (score 0):

I use testNg on windows, in the windows command prompt the execution, I use the command: java -cp bin;libs/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

Result: test run successfully

always on windows: I use git bash command, the command does not execute successfully

[image: pic]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run via cmd prompt, like this:

```
1. Go to project folder
2. Then: `java -cp [projectpath]\lib\*;[projectpath]\target org.testng.TestNG testng.xml`
```